# Power Query - split column by delimiter to fixed number of columns and keep excess fields in last column

Tags: split

My data has fixed numbers of fields followed by undetermined number of fields. How can I split it so Power Query will create fixed number of columns followed by one column with all remaining data (if any)?

Example:

```
Joe,Smith,36,01234567
Sue,Storm,28,
Jake,Runner,42,03521647,03214487,01668414
```

Result:

```
Joe  | Smith  | 36 | 01234567
Sue  | Storm  | 28 |
Jake | Runner | 42 | 03521647,03214487,01668414
```

I could Split by left-most delimiter and repeat step depending on number of columns. Any better ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the Split column...By Delimiter with comma as the delimiter and Split at set to Left-most delimiter three times.

```vb
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    #"Split Column 1" = Table.SplitColumn(Source, "Column1", Splitter.SplitTextByEachDelimiter({","}, QuoteStyle.Csv, false), {"Column1.1", "Column1.2"}),
    #"Split Column 2" = Table.SplitColumn(#"Split Column 1", "Column1.2", Splitter.SplitTextByEachDelimiter({","}, QuoteStyle.Csv, false), {"Column1.2.1", "Column1.2.2"}),
    #"Split Column 3" = Table.SplitColumn(#"Split Column 2", "Column1.2.2", Splitter.SplitTextByEachDelimiter({","}, QuoteStyle.Csv, false), {"Column1.2.2.1", "Column1.2.2.2"})
in
    #"Split Column 3"
```